# No graphical interface at startup

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Lubuntu 14.04 32 bit. 
The problem is that I can't seem to be able to use the Lubuntu graphical interface, when I start up Lubuntu all I get is a black screen with words asking for my user name and password.

Comment: When you enter your username and password, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks but i fixed the problem I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

- On the black Screen type your username and password
- Once your logged in type(in the same order that i have here, When it asks for your password type it in.):

  ```
  sudo su

  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  ```

---

Wait for it to load. This takes about 20 mins.
 Once its Done loading type: **reboot**

**And your done thats it!**
Hope this works for you!

Comment: Why did you install the Ubuntu desktop on top of Lubuntu? Why not just install Ubuntu to begin with?

Comment: If you do `sudo su` then there is no reason to use `sudo` again before `apt-get`

Comment: Because i was installing it on a slow computer, and i figured that Lubuntu would be faster so i installed Lubuntu ISO, but it kept telling me that it was Ubuntu for some reason. So i just mess around with the commands and **BOOM** Ubuntu desktop started to download so after it started downloading i really didn't care that is was Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu.

Comment: @ ElefantPhace That may be true, but i'm just showing people what worked for me.

Comment: Yes it works but `sudo su` is unnecessary. You could've just `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` if you truly wanted something lightweight

Answer (score 0):

It looks that X cannot be started or `lightdm` or other login manager is not running. Try to log in and issue `startx` command and see what happens. It will give you also some output. We will need that to help you.